# Are the Windows DLLs used for native C++ and .NET the same?

Tags: c#, .net

> Are the Windows DLLs used for native C++ and .NET the same?

I sometimes see references to common DLLs used for native Windows C++ programming when browsing .NET documentation on MSDN.

I wonder whether there are special versions of DLLs, e.g. `user32.dll`, for .NET programming, or whether the CLR calls the standard native C++ DLLs directly?

Comment: No there are not special versions of those DLLs.

Comment: @Ben - so the CLI calls the native Windows DLLs directly?

Comment: Which libraries? If you've seen this on MSDN can you provide an example?

Comment: They are the same.  Easily visible in the debugger, use Project > Properties > Debug, tick "Enable native code debugging".  And at a breakpoint use Debug > Windows > Modules to see the native DLLs.  Beyond the CLR having a direct dependency on them, the .NETFramework contains lots of pinvoke to use these DLLs.  Also the reason why .NETCore is missing a lot of features.

Comment: @Lloyd - There is the [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] etc.

Comment: @user111854 "so the CLI calls the native Windows DLLs directly?" yes, that's the "magic" of P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

They *can* be.  If the C++ DLL exposes things in the right way, it can be used by .NET natively.  Even if it doesn't, most DLL functions can be invoked from C# using a method (a way of doing things, not a C# method) called P/Invoke. P/Invoke requires some special glue declarations in the C# code that describe the functions to the C# compiler (normal DLLs don't have that type of metadata) so that it knows how to handle the data getting sent to and received from the DLL function.

.NET uses managed memory and garbage collection, which means that all the memory used by a program can be scanned by traversing a graph of all the objects in use.  C++ (and DLLs generally) doesn't do this unless it's been specially written to use .NET.  Although C++ generally uses objects, it doesn't have to.  In C++, raw memory can be allocated and the C++ runtime wouldn't be able to see any pointers that might be put into that memory.  This type of data would really mess with the .NET runtime because it wouldn't be able to know which memory it could free and which was off-limits.  The .NET runtime on the other hand, can "see" all the objects in memory, but it moves them around whenever it wants, updating the pointers as needed (which would really screw up C++).  As a result, when a .NET program invokes a non-managed DLL function, it has to convert the data going in and coming out from one memory model to the other.